# Why isnt my 1 fragment recieving the values of fragment 2? I use Bundle()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to pass the values of 1 fragment to another fragment.
I have this code:

Fragment 1:

```
    Fragment_score fragment_score = new Fragment_score();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("FINISHED_LEVELS", finishedLevels);
    bundle.putInt("FAILED_LEVELS", failedLevels);
    bundle.putInt("SKIPPED_LEVELS", skippedLevels);
    bundle.putInt("USED_HINTS", usedHints);
    fragment_score.setArguments(bundle);
```

Fragment 2:

```
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        finishedLevels = bundle.getInt("FINISHED_LEVELS",0);
        failedLevels = bundle.getInt("FAILED_LEVELS",0);
        skippedLevels = bundle.getInt("SKIPPED_LEVELS",0);
        usedHints = bundle.getInt("USED_HINTS", 0);
    }
```

But this doesnt work. I have no clue why. There is no error. But I dont recieve the values of the first fragment in the second fragment. Can anyone help me?

Comment: So where do you add that specific instance of `fragment_score` to the FragmentManager? Arguments are tied to that instance, they aren't global.

Comment: fragment_score is the second fragment.

Comment: Can you include the code where you add `fragment_score` to the FragmentManager?

Comment: There is no code where I add fragment_score to the FragmentManager.

Comment: So is the fragment where that second code snippet is running is a different instance? Where do you add *that* fragment to the FragmentManager?